# Create dynamic json object in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, dynamically-generated

I have a dictionary which is contain multiple keys and values and the values also contain the key, value pair. I am not getting how to create dynamic json using this dictionary in python. Here's the dictionary:

```
image_dict = {"IMAGE_1":{"img0":"IMAGE_2","img1":"IMAGE_3","img2":"IMAGE_4"},"IMAGE_2":{"img0":"IMAGE_1", "img1" : "IMAGE_3"},"IMAGE_3":{"img0":"IMAGE_1", "img1":"IMAGE_2"},"IMAGE_4":{"img0":"IMAGE_1"}}
```

My expected result like this :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "image": {
        "imageId": {
          "id": "IMAGE_1"
        },
        "link": {
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_2"
          },
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_3"
          },
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_4"
          }
        }
      },
      "updateData": "link"
    },
       {
      "image": {
        "imageId": {
          "id": "IMAGE_2"
        },
        "link": {
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_1"  
          },
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_3"  
          }
        }
      },
      "updateData": "link"
    },
    {
      "image": {
        "imageId": {
          "id": "IMAGE_3"
        },
        "link": {
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_1"  
          },
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_2"  
          }
        }
      },
      "updateData": "link"
    } ,
    {
      "image": {
        "imageId": {
          "id": "IMAGE_4"
        },
        "link": {
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_1"  
          }
        }
      },
      "updateData": "link"
    } 
  ]
}
```

I tried to solve it but I didn't get expected result.

```
result = {"data":[]}

for k,v in sorted(image_dict.items()):
    for a in sorted(v.values()):
        result["data"].append({"image":{"imageId":{"id": k},
                                        "link":{"target":{"id": a}}},"updateData": "link"})
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Comment: The `json` part is totally (well, mostly) irrelevant here, your question is "how do I transform this source dict into that target dict.

Comment: Yeah you right @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @rajendrapawar, your expected json is invalid. There can not be repeated keys within a dict `.. "link": {
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_2"
          },
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_3"
          },
          "target": {
            "id": "IMAGE_4"
          }  ..`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yeah I know but I want like that only

Comment: @rajendrapawar, you can not obtain invalid structure, at least, not in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python dictionaries you can't have 2 values with the same key. So you can't have multiple targets all called  "target". So you can index them. Also I don't know what this question has to do with dynamic objects but here's the code I got working:

```
import re
dict_res = {}
ind = 0
for image in image_dict:
    lin_ind = 0
    sub_dict = {'image' + str(ind): {'imageId': {image}, 'link': {}}}
    for sub in image_dict[image].values():
        sub_dict['image' + str(ind)]['link'].update({'target' + str(lin_ind): {'id': sub}})
        lin_ind += 1
    dict_res.update(sub_dict)
    ind += 1
dict_res = re.sub('target\d', 'target', re.sub('image\d', 'image', str(dict_res)))
print dict_res
```

Comment: What is it that's different other than the index numbers?

Comment: You can turn it into a string. And use the re function. I made the edit on the code that does this for you.